# Popup window closing when trying to load same page in the popup

Tags: javascript, html, window

I created pop up window using `window.open(url,name,properties)`  as popup.html
I want to load the same page(popup.html) in the same popup window.
But it is not allowing me and closing the popup window.
Why it is happening like this.?

Any response is highly appreciated
Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "login.htm?login=true";
var strWindowName ="newWindow";
var strWindowFeatures = "left=0,top=0,width=1200,height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var windowObjectReference = window.open(url,strWindowName,strWindowFeatures);
this.window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Can we see your code please? A window does not close by itself.

Comment: If you don't keep your child window idle and click the link, the window won't be closed?

Comment: @bagonyi Yes you are correct. It is happening when window idle for some time and then click any link it is getting closed

Comment: @putvande I added code snippet for creating new window

Comment: What is happening on link click? Any server-side code executed?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes. Server side call will be made to redirect to some other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that, it is getting closed due to the line `this.window.close();`
and if i comment this line, then it is causing to go infinite loop of window calling.